# Android splash Activity only shows up once

Tags: android, android-activity, splash-screen

I have created a slash screen for my Android app following [this tutorial](http://www.barebonescoder.com/2010/04/a-simple-android-splash-screen/). Basically it's just start a Thread in the onCreate() of the splash Activity, and wait for a short period of time before switch to the main activity.

This works fine ... only on the first time running. The splash screen only shows up once after installation or rebooting my phone. On the second time, the app just skips the splash Activity like it doesn't exists.

I suspect it has something to do with Android Activity life cycle, maybe the app doesn't really exist and stays in memory. I tried killing it by: 1) Using the "Advanced Task Manager" app, and 2) Programmatically killing it in onDestory(), but none of those worked. The splash screen still won't show up after the first time.

Can anyone help me with this? Thanks a lot,

Comment: What do you need your splash screen for? If it's to 'disguise' some preparation work that might take time to complete then that's generally acceptable. On the other hand if it's just there for the sake of it, many users will get tired of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of putting it in your `onCreate()` you could try to put it in the `onStart()` method. That way it'll show for each *launch* not just each creation which might get around your lifecycle issue.